# How to Write Successful or Failed Logfile after executed the SQL query Exe in C#

Tags: c#

I am Beginner for Development and i am creating exe file to execute the SQL scripts. I have 3 doubts here.
1. How to get the file name from the folder at run time. (Currently i did hardcore)
2. How to write a log file after executed the query.
3. How to show alert message after executed the query? (Patch executed successful / Patch execution failed)

Please find my script mentioned below;

```
var txtconn = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Patch\Connstrng.txt");
var txtfile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:Users\Patch\Script.txt");
string[] sqlqry = txtfile.Split(new[] {"~GO~"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var conn = new SqlConnection(txtconn);
var cmd = new SqlCommand("query", conn);
conn.Open();
foreach (var query in sqlqry){
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}
conn.Close();
```

// Need to show alert message as "Patch executed successful. Please send Result Log to Support
// Need to create the result log file.'

Comment: Is every query going to be insert/update/delete? Also, how do you decide which file(s) from folder you will use? Or is it every file in folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use a try catch block

```
        foreach (var query in sqlqry)
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string logPath = ""; //Path for log
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Ran query " + query); //W
                }
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Patch executed successful. Please send Result Log to Support // Need to create the result log file.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle Error
            }
        }
```

You'll need to set a path for where you want to write your log file. After executing the query, the StreamWriter class will write whatever you want to that log file. (The true parameter indicates that you will append to this log file, so each entry doesn't overwrite the last). Then you can use a MessageBox to display the information.

Because the executing of the query is ran inside of a try block, if it fails (some sort of exception happens) it will enter the catch block, in which case you will need to handle that error, perhaps by popping up another message box or logging something to the file.